# Нужно ли здесь выделение запятыми?

Tags: пунктуация

Вечером после дня рождения я пойду гулять. Где и почему?

Answer (score 1):

Здесь два обстоятельства со значением времени, при этом второе обстоятельство может быть обособлено, если ему придать значение **уточнения**. Обособление зависит **от коммуникативной ситуации**.

(1) Что ты делаешь завтра? — Завтра я иду на день рождения, а вечером **после дня рождения** я пойду гулять.

(2) Встретимся завтра? — Завтра я иду на день рождения. — А вечером? — Вечером, **после дня рождения**, я иду гулять.